# Indexing book in java

Tags: java, indexing

I'm trying to write a program that takes in a text file as input, adds words in it as keys and the associated to the words values schould be page numbers they are located in. Text looks like this:

> Page1
>   blah bla bl
>   Page2
>   some blah

So for word "blah" output must be

> blah : [1,2].

I only inserted the keys, but I can't figure out how to insert associated values to them. Here's what I have so far:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
    try {
    Map <String, List<Integer>> library 
            = new TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>();
        String line = reader.readLine(); 
        while (line != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                String word = tokens[i];
                if (!library.containsKey(word) 
                         && !word.startsWith("Page")) {
                    library.put(word, new LinkedList<Integer>());
                    if (tokens[0].startsWith("Page")
                           && library.containsKey(word)) {
                        List<Integer> pages = library.get(word);
                        int page = getNum(tokens[0]);
                        pages.add(page);
                        page++;
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         line = reader.readLine();
      }
 }
```

To get number of page I use this method

```
 private static int getNum(String s) {
    int result = 0;
    int p = 1;
    int i = s.length() - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        int d = s.charAt(i) - '0';
        if (d >= 0 && d <= 9) {
            result += d * p;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        i--;
        p *= 10;
    }
    return result;     
 }
```

Thank's for all Your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pages` variable is declared inside the scope of your inner `if` statement. Once that block ends the variable is out of scope and undefined. If you want to use the list of pages later then it needs to be declared as a class variable.

I assume you are using `pages` to later generate a table of contents. But it's not strictly necessary as you can generate it later from your word index - I'll demonstrate how to do that below.

You also need to declare a `currentPage` variable which hold the latest 'PageN' text you have seen. There's no need to increment this manually: you should just store the number in the text (which copes with blank pages).

Page numbers seem to always be on their own line so page detection should be on the line text not on the word (which copes with situations where a line reads 'for more information see Page72').

It's also worth checking that there's a valid page number before your first word.

So putting that all together your code should be structured something like the following:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> index = new TreeMap<>();
int currentPage = -1;
String currentLine;
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (isPage(currentLine)) {
        currentPage = getPageNum(currentLine);
    } else {
        assert currentPage > 0;
        for (String word: words(currentLine)) {
            if (!index.contains(word))
                index.put(word, new TreeSet<>());
            index.get(word).add(currentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

I've separated methods `words`, `isPage` and `getPageNum` but you seem to have working code for all of those.

I've also changed the List of pages to a Set to reflect the fact that you only want a word-page reference once in the index.

To get an ordered list of all pages from the index use:

```
index.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream).distinct().sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That's assuming Java8 but it's not too hard to convert if you don't have streams.

If you are going to generate a reverse index (pages to words) then for efficiency reasons you should probably create the reverse map (`Map<Integer, List<String>>`) as you are processing the words.

Comment: Thank you! This solved allmost all the problem. Could you help me with another question? If some word occurs at the page more then once, I'm getting an output like "search word    word:[1, 2, 2, 2]". So how to avoid such repeatings? The output that I need in this case would be "search word    word:[1, 2]"

Comment: The simplest thing to do is turn the list into a set - that means there's only one copy of each page in the list. I'll edit the code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this. I'm not totally sure how you're using the pages, but this code will check if library contains the word (like you already have) and then if it doesn't it will add the page number to the list for that word.

```
if (!library.containsKey(word) && !word.startsWith("Page")) {
    library.put(word, new LinkedList<Integer>());
}
else {
    library.put(word, library.get(word).add(page));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But your advise doesn't really work. I use pages to build some sort of list of contents. I also have a lookup-method in my programm, so wenn I'm searching for word "haley", I expected an output  haley : 5,12 (if pages that begins with page5 and page12 containe word "haley" )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem then. If you're trying to add pages (the list of contents) then you could do "library.get(word).addAll(pages)".

Comment: Sorry, if my questions seem stupid to you, but I have really  hard time understanding how to solve this problem.
<br\>If input file contains text like:
<br\>Page1
<br\>you should try 
<br\>Page2
<br\>something like this

<br\>my String[] tokens looks like <br\>this
<br\>Page1
<br\>you
<br\>should
<br\>try
<br\>Page2
<br\>something
<br\>like
<br\>this

Comment: My problem is that in pages are saved integers  the word "Page" ends with, other words in file don't contain numbers, so with library.get(word).getAll(pages) I only get the result I need for words "Page1", "Page2" etc., but these words don't even suppose to be in library.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in this piece of logic:

```
                if (tokens[0].startsWith("Page")
                       && library.containsKey(word)) {
```

clearly you are adding page numbers only when line starts with Page otherwise the logic inside if condition is not executed so you never updated the page number for any words.